# Validate particular range using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want validate text box with particular range having format like :

```
1-99
```

I am using regex :

```
/^(?:100|[1-9]\d|\d)-(?:100|[1-9]\d|\d)$/
```

It works for me but little problem that is it accept this:

```
55-50
```

And it shouldn't, this is wrong.

how can I correct this?

Comment: I doubt if you should use regexp for this. Why not split on the `-`?

Comment: Regular expressions cannot perform logical operations. You can validate that there is a number followed by a hyphen followed by another number, but you will have to validate the first number is less than the other as a secondary step.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to check validation between the both number you have to use logical operations to check if the forst number is less than second, so you couldn't use regex in this case instead use `if/else` statement :

```js
var input = "55-50";

if(input.indexOf('-')){
    var input_arr = input.split('-');
    
    if(input_arr.length==2 && parseInt(input_arr[0])<parseInt(input_arr[1]))
        alert("Accepted");
    else
        alert("Not accepted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it has been told early regexp is not the method for validating ranges. The better way is to use `if/else` statements. But you are not restricted in usage of regexp for validating input string on the particular format.

F.i., if you'd like to enable the end user to enter the range in the format `number1-number2`, you could check the string for compliance to this format and check its parts for complaince to the condition `number1 <= number2`. If all these checks are done you could do something useful or decline, if checks are fail.

```
function validRange(rangeStr, min, max) {
    var m = rangeStr.match(/^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$/);

    if ( m && m[1] >= min && m[2] <= max && m[1] <= m[2] ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

var s = '1-99';
var s = '55-50';

if ( validRange(s, 1, 99) ) {
    // do something useful
}
```

The code above is just skeleton for the further improvements but it can be used now. But the code could be too complicated, if you or your customers will request to implement something more complex like ability to enter single number, lists of numbers (separated with comma, semicolons etc), mixed ranges or any combination of all of them.